# Can't get legacy versions of PHP to use MySQL under Plesk and CentOS

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

I am changing my hosting provider and migrating from cPanel to Plesk. Everything is nice and I am exited but I can't get old PHP scripts working which still use MySQL instead of MySQLi or PDO.

Plesk lets different accounts or domains use different versions of PHP. Fortunately even older versions that still recognize MySQL are available (5.4, 5.5, 5.6) and I have actually managed to make one of my domains to use PHP 5.6 but although it works there, MySQL is still not available. MySQLi is working with PHP 5.6 but all point of downgrading PHP was to get MySQL working. It simply complains: 'Call to undefined function mysql_connect()'.

As far as I can see mysql extension is installed. phpinfo() shows sections of mysql and mysqli and mysqlnd and even pdo_mysql. mysql.so is there at /opt/plesk/php/5.6/lib64/php/modules.

I have tried all the options in Plesk and I have edited the ini files (extension=mysql.so) but no progress. I have spent all day already. Have also tried different handlers.

One thing that I have noticed is on the phpinfo() page. 'Configure Command' section contains among the other strings, the following: '--without-mysql'. I don't see a way in Plesk to remove this. And I don't see a way to change configure options for PHP. Is this the reason why mysql_ functions don't work? How to solve this? I got it working easily with cPanel but Plesk is new to me and Google has not been helpful today. Please advice!

Comment: Did you ask the provider?

Comment: Unless there are other things in the app which require a legacy version, it might be quicker and easier to just include a shim in your application which provides the `mysql_xxxx` function names but then actually uses mysqli to make the db calls. There are a couple around, e.g. https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim . Just `require` that file at the start of your script, before you use any db code. That way you get the benefit of being on a supported version of PHP, while giving yourself a little more time to move away from the ancient unsupported and insecure `mysql_` API.

Comment: P.S. I agree you could ask the provider, but TBH they probably want to be rid of the security risks of such an old API. So I suspect they have quite good reasons for disabling it. And if it's shared hosting, they probably don't want to put both you and other customers on the same host at extra risk by enabling it. I could be wrong, but it looks like they've gone to some trouble to disable it. mysqli (and PDO) has been around since PHP 5.0 (released in 2004!!) so it's not like there hasn't already been plenty of time for people to upgrade.

Comment: No it's not shared hosting. I am moving from classical VPS to cloud. So I got a server and installed the image of CentOS 7 with Plesk there. So it's not the provider's hack. Don't know if Plesk provides doctored versions of legacy PHP.

Comment: Well if you really want to try and get it working I would contact the hosting provider for support in the first instance - they know their environment. But personally I'd use the shim on PHP7, and then work on re-writing the apps, urgently, as you're more than likely at risk of SQL injection and other issues.